# Jquery upload multiple - Add more image instead of change old uploads with new upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I am building a web app that can upload multiply with jquery upload manually, not using any libraries, so the case is, when i upload multiple, e.g : 3 images (eg : image_1.jpg, image_2.jpg, image_3.jpg), I have succeed to get the preview of 3 images, here's my js code:

```
$('button#Images').on('change', function(){
    var filelists = this.files || [];        

    $.each(filelists, function(i, filelist){
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $( '.preview-' + i ).html('<img class="image-preview" src="'+ e.target.result +'" width=75/>');                
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(filelist);
    });                                         
});
```

my question is when I want to add more image e.g (image_4.jpg,image_5.jpg), the preview changes to (image_4.jpg, image_5.jpg,). i want if i click button#images, then the old images not replaced with the new upload files, i want it to combine the old uploads with the new one such as (image_1.jpg, image_2.jpg, image_3.jpg, image_4.jpg, image_5.jpg,),

is there any way to do it?
sorry newbie here

update fiddle : 
https://jsfiddle.net/vxj3bt6d/

your help will be appreciated

Comment: please add your html code to help you out or create a fiddle example

Comment: i have update it for example sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var number = 0;
$('#Images').on('change', function(){
    var filelists = this.files || [];        
    $.each(filelists, function(i, filelist){
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $( '.preview-' + number ).html('<img class="image-preview" src="'+ e.target.result +'" width=75/>'); 
            number ++ ;
            
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(filelist);
         
    });  
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preview-0"></div>
<div class="preview-1"></div>
<div class="preview-2"></div>
<div class="preview-3"></div>
<div class="preview-4"></div>
<div class="preview-5"></div>


<form>
<input type="file" id="Images" accept="image/*" maxlength="50" name="bentoImages[]" multiple="true" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" />                                                
</form>
```

Please check the Code, the value of **i** is always getting "0" , so with an external value of number able to put image in different `div`.

Check the updated fiddle too [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akit/vxj3bt6d/1/)

Thanks

Comment: ah thanks for the answer, the preview is working, is there a solution for me to get the formdata of all images with it?

Comment: Formatted image as in ?